# Have table value execute function using key in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make a menu system in Lua using the only data structure available: tables. I have two menus: connectionmenu and mainmenu.

I want to be able to switch between the menus. For example, from mainmenu, go to connectionmenu, and then that becomes the currentmenu that is displayed.

Here is my code: Note that I am using a library called onelua for the psp to display the menu, however my question is directly related to core lua and tables.

```
function changemenu(menu)
    currentmenu = menu
end

connectionmenu = {"Connection Menu Title"};
mainmenu = {"Main Menu Title"}
currentmenu = connectionmenu

connectionmenu["Connection Menu"] = changemenu(mainmenu)
mainmenu["Main Menu"] = "test value"
```

Now how can I execute connectionmenu["Connection Menu"]'s function?

I've tried:

```
return [currentmenu["Connection Menu"]]
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your meaning.Because I can't add a comment, I will give some advice.

First, if you want add a function to menu(connectionmenu or mainmenu), you can do as upstairs.

Secondly, if you want to execut changemenu function.You need give the element the function, not a return value of the function.You can modify like this:

```
connectionmenu["Connection Menu"] = changemenu
```

And, execute the function:

```
return currentmenu["Connection Menu"]();
```

I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well first thing you need to make your function a part of the table:

```
connectionmenu = {
    "Title Here",
    func = function (firstarg, secondarg)
        -- Function body here
    end
}
```

Then, you can run the function by calling the func method of the table:

```
currentmenu.func(firstarg, secondarg)
```